# I am facing trouble while trying to record browser using NeoLoad

Tags: testing, mobile, browser, neoload

Hi I am new to performance testing. I am trying to record browser application but my phone is not getting connected, so i am not able to record the steps.
Could anyone help me out with the issue.
I am trying to record in tunnel mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to record a web application that is running inside a web browser on your device, then the Proxy method is the first method to try. It's the most simple method to use in many cases.

You can even record it with a modern browser like Chrome directly from your desktop with the "Identify as" feature of the Recorder.

For Proxy based recording and Tunnel mode, ensure that the device is running on the same Network than the machine running NeoLoad (WIFI), or at least the device must be able to connect to the NeoLoad machine.

For proxy based recording, modify the proxy settings of the device so that the NeoLoad machine is used as the proxy, port 8090. Then you can record.

For tunnel mode recording (if you cannot modify the proxy settings), modify the DNS settings of the device so that the NeoLoad machine is used as the DNS of the device.

You can have more info in the [Neotys](http://www.neotys.com/documents/doc/neoload/latest/en/html/index.html#4438.htm) guide for mobile testing:

If you still have an issue, then I'm sure Neotys support will be happy to help you.

Christophe
Neotys